# handle dojo EdgeToEdgeStoreList event

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, handler

I create an EdgeToEdgeStoreList from `dojox/mobile` as follow:

```
<ul id="listCustomers"></ul>

storeCustomers = new Memory({data: data, idProperty: "label"});
    var listCustomers = new EdgeToEdgeStoreList({
      select: "single",
      store: storeCustomers
}, "listCustomers");
listCustomers.startup();
```

then I want to handle the `onCheckStateChanged` event:

```
var listCustomers = dom.byId("listCustomers");
on(listCustomers, "checkStateChanged", function (listItem, newState) {
    console.log(listItem, newState);
});
```

but this never fires.
What is the correct method?

It's ok also a way to get an array of selected items (just one in my specific case, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, either use the listitems onclick, or if you want to use checkStateChanged you have to add that listener Widget.

```
   var listCustomers = dijit.registry.byId("listCustomers");
on(listCustomers, "checkStateChanged", function (listItem, newState) {
    console.log(listItem, newState);
});
```

Comment: It works. The only difference was I retrived the DOM item rather than the dijit one.